# Any risk in providing my address for a "trial product"?

Tags: scams

I run an online store and received an unsolicited message through the customer contact form.

They claim to be a manufacturer producing items which would fit well in my store. Their website and facebook page seems legitimate.

They seem to be interested in setting up a relationship where they are my wholesaler.

I've asked them to send me a trial product. Is there any risk in giving out my address to receive the product?

Going forward, how do I ensure they are a legitimate manufacturer and not aiming to scam me?

Comment: Do you have a PO Box or something similar for other business items that need to be mailed to you?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Not at the moment but I could give my local delivery office's address and ask them to hold the item for me, although that takes a bit of effort to set up. Is the risk significant enough to warrant the extra effort? And if so, what are the specific risks?

Comment: The comment was a way to understand your operating environment. If you had a "business shipping address" and were getting dozens of items every week, then one more would be low risk.

Comment: Definitely set up a PO Box, if for no other reason than that you don't want some irate customer egging your house.